# Android OpenGL export to phone

Tags: android, opengl-es, galaxy

I just finished an Android app which includes a openGL side and another side with layouts.The project was created for Android 2.2 and it worked fine on the 2.2 and 4 Android device emulator.The moment i exported the app to a Galaxy Nexus phone, the OpenGL side is white.
Is there another way to export apps with OpenGL?

Comment: Do you do any opengl error checking w/ glGetError? There could be lots of reasons why it works on one device and not another.

Comment: The error isn't in the exporting, it's in the minor differences between OpenGL implementations. Even with regular OpenGL you'll get small, weird differences between NVIDIA and AMD drivers, sometimes even between driver versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved when i realised the pictures were not power of 2 x power of 2.When that was fixed, it worked like a char,